# Phonegap : window.location forgets my css and my style

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, cordova

thanks for this website ;)

I am developing an iPhone app using phonegap and jquery mobile.

On my first page I make a redirection to the login.html page.
I only put this in my index_bis.js file : window.location.href ='login.html';

The redirection works, but there is no style on my page. The style works when I don't redirect! :(

An idea ? Thanks a lot!

This is part of my index.html :

```
<head>
    <title>...</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css" />
    </head>   

<body>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index_bis.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do window.location, the current page is replaced with the called page and so all ur styles references are lost.

You should be looking at a single page application architecture using JQM. The first html page loads and all other pages are loaded asynchronously using ajax added to the DOM. Please carefully read [this documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/page-links.html) and you will get an idea.

Multi-page link is how you need to link pages.

if you wanna navigate programmatically, you need to use the [$.mobile.changePage()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/) method

Comment: I am having a look. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe stupid question, but do you have in the login.html thae same style and libraries included? 
And have they correct paths?

Just try to point to possible problems :)

Comment: No I don't!
But when I use a button to link index.html and login.html, the style works ..